# Is that OK to leave a small endless loop script running on server?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2

Looks like I need to update the full scenario here for all.

Our users need to pick up whatever they need from our file server to sync to remote location, but users have limited permissions on file server to move files around. so here is my task:

> create a tool that user can use to pickup data and sync to remote
>   location. DFS and 3rd party tools are not options, must be codes made
>   by our own and everything must be running on background.

Here is my way to do it and it is working now. I have made 3 pieces of components:

**A**** HTA application with VBS sitting on user PC providing user a file browser to pickup data.

**B**** A shared location that allows that HTA to write data path to a txt file. any path in this text file will be made as softlink into a final location.

**C**** A final location on file server holds all softlinks.

Here is how basically it works:

User pick a data from file server by using HTA I made, It will write the full data path to the the 000.txt file on the shared location. My endless looping script monitors this shared location, if 000.txt file is created by any user in this shared folder, it will call up another script to read all data paths in this 000.txt and using `mklink` to make softlinks based on the paths user provided and outputs softlinks to the final location, then deletes 000.txt file. All softlinks on this final location will be synced by `robocopy` during the night on schedule. There are more functions required in my HTA application, there is no need to talk about it.

Since no one here talking about coding, so I deleted my endless loop code, This loop script starts with Windows and running as a service. I can start/stop it anytime I want. It basically  just monitors that shared folder, if any user creates 000.txt file in there, it will call up `mklink.bat` to make softlins and 000.txt will be deleted by `mklink.bat` when softlink are made. The reason that I use an endless loop instead of task scheduler is user need to see results in that final location right after they submit the data path. I thought the minimal interval of task scheduler is one min, (@MikeAWood said it can be 1 second. Thanks!) so I made a this 2 seconds interval endless loop to monitor that shared folder.

My question was the following:

> Is this a good idea to running a endless loop on server like forever
>   to monitor a folder?
>
> I monitored the resources usage on server while this script is
>   running. I dont see any significant consumings...so I guess it will be
>   harmless  right?

If task scheduler can handle 1 second interval, **I guess my question is solved.** Thanks to you all.

Or if you have better way to do this or any opinion on the way I do it.

Comment: `Is that OK to leave a small endless loop script running on server?` No, no it's not.  This is the type of thing that makes senior admins break the fingers of junior admins.  I'd ask what you're trying to do, but I'm worried that you'd tell me... there's a much better way to do whatever you're trying to do, and that's what you should be doing.  If nothing else, use a scheduled task, but I'm pretty sure that you should seriously refactor your approach to whatever you're doing.

Comment: Note `timeout /T 1` will wait for one second (or a keypress unless you also add `/NOBREAK`)

Comment: @HopelessN00b DFS, of cuz I would like to use it if my boss is not an old fashion....everything must be running by script made by our own.....

Comment: @rootloop your boss wants to make an unsupportable environment.  maybe because he's old fashioned.  maybe because he thinks it means they can never fire him.  whatever the reason, that's a good sign that you should look elsewhere for employment. You won't learn many useful, transferable skills in an environment like that.

Comment: if you want to monitor a directory, maybe one of these help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/244941

Comment: So is your boss making you roll your own server operating system too? _Not_ using the operating system feature that was _designed_ to solve this problem is absurd.

Comment: Actually, Task Scheduler will let you manually type in "1 second" if you really want to use that as a duration.  But since you are introducing a delay if there are no existing files, running it once a minute should effect the same "delay".  Truth is, once the process runs, it will just sleep again for 60 seconds.  My vote would be to use a folder watcher or something less "me mongo me use big hammer" of an approach.  But task scheduler will do what you are asking. But I agree that it isn't a best practice..

Comment: You don't want to use Task Scheduler's Trigger set to 1 second.  Even your script you had posted earlier sleeps for 60 seconds.  You very likely will have issues if you try to keep brute force scanning a folder like that.  Just step away.  Plus, whatever your bosses beef with DFS-R is, odds are it was the same experience many of us had at first with it. But many of us rely on it everyday to handle our workloads, at the worst, you can certainly "test" it again and prove it's worth.  The robocopy suggestion is what I would likely go with instead.

Comment: JTFC. That solution sounds unstable and fragile. I don't care if your boss won't let you use DFS-R, you should set up a test environment, using DFS-R so you can prove that he's wrong. Remember,  it's easier to ask for forgiveness, than permission.

Comment: [This question is being discussed on meta.](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6256/126632)

Comment: Perhaps you should scrap this question and try again, perhaps on SuperUser. Please try to be clear the first time. If you keep editing the context of a question, any past answers will become irrelevant.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As a general alternative to this: put your script in Task Scheduler and trigger it every minute, two minutes, whatever. This is more reliable, as your process with survive reboots or script errors. Using Scheduled Tasks not only allows your process to survive reboots, as mentioned already, but can also [make your task deployable to a large number of servers via Group Policy Preferences.](https://web.archive.org/web/20200723194918/http://www.mdmarra.com/2014/04/managing-scheduled-tasks-from-group.html) Your current solution is an enemy to both scalability and reliability.

As for the actual script you're talking about - it seems like you're re-inventing a Frankenstein's Monster of DFS-R and/or Robocopy.

---

[DFS-R](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/cc773238(WS.10).aspx) is a scalable, mature file replication tool that is built into Windows Server. You should see if you can use it for this situation. Microsoft has put way more engineering brain-power into DFS-R than you could ever put into a script that does the same thing.

Also, even if you can't use DFS-R for some reason, [robocopy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145.aspx) has a `/mir` switch, which will mirror directories. If you really can't use DFS-R for some reason, at least use something like this in a script.

Comment: dude...this is the task i ve assigned on ...must create something my our own, cuz my boss had some bad history with DFS, so he wont trust DFS anymore lol....

Comment: Well then, a good part of your job is managing the technical expectations of your management chain. If you aren't up to the task, you should probably look for a new job.

Comment: @RootLoop sorry, there's no right answer for "my boss won't let me use the right tool." For what it's worth, I did put more than one recommendation here.

Comment: `you should probably look for a new job` This is probably the worst advice i've ever read

Comment: @krisFR - You haven't been burned enough, yet, by people who are in over their heads creating disasters. Just wait-- eventually it'll happen to you.

Comment: @krisFR If you're on a train and you can see it's going off a cliff, you can only argue with the conductor about whether he should pull the brake for so long before it becomes a moot point -- at which point you can either stay on the train and hope for a miracle, or engage your common sense and jump off the train.

Answer (score 9):

You should be commended for asking about your approach.  Its easy to run with the first idea you have, but better to validate with with others.

Several issues with your approach:

- It has to be restarted manually everytime the server restarts
- It requires you to stay logged onto the console with credentials that have access to source & destination
- There are already tools that do this (DFS, scheduled tasks, etc.)

(Some of these issues can be addressed as you've mentioned with the service.)  That said, only you can assess the validity of any particular solution to the problem you face.  At least now you have options.

Comment: The script will start with windows. I made this batch file runnaing as  a service..DFS is not an option as what I ve been told by boss....

Answer (score 5):

There are surely better ways to do that than running endless loop. Endless loops are pain, and causes frustration at all levels to everyone. Please don't do that.

Comment: I monitored the resources usage on server while this script is running. I dont see any significant consumings...so I guess it will be harmless right?

Comment: its harmless at this time, yes. But in future it can be a redundant code, or if the file is locked, what would happen?

Comment: Looking only at system performance during normal operations is *not* a comprehensive risk assessment.

Answer (score 5):

I'm curious why you are asking. Several people have offered alternative solutions and the response seems to be that you were ordered to do it this way. Are you looking for alternatives or are you looking for ammunition to go back to your manager and protest doing it this way?

The reasons for not doing it this way have been enumerated in other answers:

- it is prone to failure in that it won't survive a failure, or a system restart, or any kind of processing error.
- it requires effort on your part (as opposed to a vendor's) to maintain
- there are security risks to this method
- it is relatively inefficient

As far as alternatives go, I too had a bad experience with DFS and used DoubleTake Replication with great results. However a subsequent release of DFS resolved my issues with DFS and now we use that for DR replication across a WAN.